# How to add L2 Regularization to ResNet50? How to resolve the problem of overfitting?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, resnet, transfer-learning

1. Loading ResNet model and adding L2 Regularization:

```
resnet_base = ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(224,224,3))
alpha = 1e-5
for layer in resnet_base.layers:
  if isinstance(layer, keras.layers.Conv2D) or isinstance(layer, keras.layers.Dense):
    layer.add_loss(keras.regularizers.l2(alpha)(layer.kernel))
  if hasattr(layer, 'bias_regularizer') and layer.use_bias:
    layer.add_loss(keras.regularizers.l2(alpha)(layer.bias))
```

2. Adding a FC layer on top of the ResNet base:

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(resnet_base)
model.add(layers.AveragePooling2D())
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(128, activation= 'relu', kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(alpha)))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.6))
model.add(layers.Dense(8, activation = 'softmax', kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(alpha)))
model.summary()
```

3. Freezing the ResNet layers to warm-up the FC layer:

```
for layer in resnet_base.layers[:]:
  layer.trainable = False
model.compile(optimizer = SGD(learning_rate = 0.0001, momentum = 0.9, nesterov = False), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
batch_size = 32
history = model.fit(train_generator,
                             steps_per_epoch=14206//batch_size, #14206 - training samples
                             epochs=5,
                             validation_data=validation_generator,
                             validation_steps=3546//batch_size) #3546 - validation samples
```

[image]
4. Unfreezing some layers of ResNet base and training the model again:

```
for layer in resnet_base.layers[:165]:
  layer.trainable = False
for layer in resnet_base.layers[165:]:
  layer.trainable = True
model.compile(optimizer = SGD(learning_rate = 0.0001, momentum = 0.9, nesterov = False),
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
             metrics=['accuracy'])
nepochs=150
history = model.fit(train_generator,
                             steps_per_epoch=14206//batch_size, #14206 - training samples
                             epochs=nepochs,
                             validation_data=validation_generator,
                             validation_steps=3546//batch_size) #3546 - validation samples
```

[image]
With all this, I'm not able to resolve the problem of Overfitting. I have augmented the training data and have used preprocess_input function for both training and validation dataset. I have followed the instructions provided here: https://jricheimer.github.io/keras/2019/02/06/keras-hack-1/ for implementing L2 Regularization.

Comment: Can you add some image details and loss/accuracy plots?

Comment: I have added the images as requested. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

- Use Global Pooling and try to get rid of the Fully connected layer completely.

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(resnet_base)
model.add(layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D())
model.add(layers.Dense(8, activation = 'softmax')
model.summary()
```

- Don't use regularization in the last layer.
- Try training for fewer epochs or use EarlyStopping.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/EarlyStopping

- Use an augmentation library to increase training samples.

https://github.com/mdbloice/Augmentor

Comment: I have actually used Callbacks: ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping.
I wanted to know if I have implemented L2 Regularization appropriately. Could you please comment on that?
Could you explain the necessity of using Augmentor of your choice while I have already used ImageDataGenerator() from Keras.

Comment: Your metrics don't suggest any major overfitting. No, as I said the last layer shouldn't have any regularization as far as I know. You may try increasing alpha. Also try the Global Pooling.

Comment: The model's performance is very poor on unseen data and when exposed to the wild.

Comment: That's normal for any model, you can't expect your model to work on any distribution of data. Your validation metrics are good so your model is most probably not overfitting. As far as test set, don't use test set which is drastically different than training data.

Comment: Can you add a few samples of training and test data as I suggested initially?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, this is not a right way to add regularization of pre-trained models. There are some extra steps that needs to be done, see here : https://sthalles.github.io/keras-regularizer/

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over all the layers of `Resnet50`, see if this layer can be regularized using the `kernel_regularizer` parameter, and apply regularization on that layer.

```
def apply_regularization(
    model: tf.keras.Model,
    l1_regularization: Optional[float],
    l2_regularization: Optional[float],
) -> tf.keras.Model:
    for layer in model.layers:
        if hasattr(layer, "kernel_regularizer"):
            if l1_regularization:
                layer.kernel_regularizer = tf.keras.regularizers.l1(l1_regularization)
            if l2_regularization:
                layer.kernel_regularizer = tf.keras.regularizers.l2(l2_regularization)
    return model
```